# Detecting Facebook Button

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent

on the HTC Chacha and HTC Sensation, there is a dedicated facebook button located outside on the phone's interface.

I'm trying to find ways to detect the pressing of this button, preferably through identifying the intents that are passed . Any ideas?